# Fail to write to S3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a file to Amazon S3.

```
val creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
val amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(creds)
val filePath = "/service2/2019/06/30/21"
val fileContent = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
val meta = new ObjectMetadata();
amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketName, filePath, new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes), meta)
```

The program is finished with no error, but no file is written into the bucket.

Comment: You could have a look at [Benji](https://zengularity.github.io/benji/) S3/DSL (I'm a contributor of) for easy integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` argument seems to have a typo. Try without the initial forward slash

```
val filePath = "service2/2019/06/30/21"
```

instead of

```
val filePath = "/service2/2019/06/30/21"
```